# Get property of a grouped result from reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript, reduce, for-in-loop

In grouped result I need the property of vendor and store in new array. but the give me some error. the error is `Error: words is not defined`.
how can I get vendor property from grouped list?
it is about to get result and store in new property.

```js
const cart = {
    "_id": 2,
    "owner": 7,
    "products": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b2"
        },
        "product": 1,
        "vendor": 1,
        "quantity": 2
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b3"
        },
        "product": 2,
        "vendor": 1,
        "quantity": 1
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b4"
        },
        "product": 4,
        "vendor": 2,
        "quantity": 1
    }],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-06-21T06:46:40.111Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-07-09T11:04:04.459Z"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "totalPrice": 265
}

const product = cart.products;
var grouped = product.reduce((dictionary, p) => {
  dictionary[p.vendor] = dictionary[p.vendor] || [];
  dictionary[p.vendor].push(p);
  return dictionary;
}, {})
for (const p in grouped) {
  console.log(grouped[p].vendor)
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You have `words.filter(word => word.length > 6)` but you never defined an array named `words`. What are you trying to filter?

Comment: You never use the `result` variable, so what is that line for at all?

Comment: You also never use `f`, what is that for?

Comment: Just get rid of the line `const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);` It serves no purpose, and it's referencing a nonexistent variable.

Comment: OMG ‍♂️, I forgot to clean the code. actually I missed. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the 2 lines of code which do nothing, I think you're trying to get the id of the vendor for each group - in which case this is just `p` in your code at the bottom which logs:

```js
const cart = {"_id":2,"owner":7,"products":[{"_id":{"$oid":"5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b2"},"product":1,"vendor":1,"quantity":2},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b3"},"product":2,"vendor":1,"quantity":1},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b4"},"product":4,"vendor":2,"quantity":1}],"createdAt":{"$date":"2020-06-21T06:46:40.111Z"},"updatedAt":{"$date":"2020-07-09T11:04:04.459Z"},"__v":0,"totalPrice":265}

//const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
//const f = cart.products.filter(p => p.vendor == 1);
const product = cart.products;
var grouped = product.reduce((dictionary, p) => {
  dictionary[p.vendor] = dictionary[p.vendor] || [];
  dictionary[p.vendor].push(p);
  return dictionary;
}, {})
let vendor;
for (const p in grouped) {
  console.log("vendor=", p, " count of items=", grouped[p].length)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. the solution was really good and I understood very well.

Answer (score 2):

```
const cart = {
  _id: 2,
  owner: 7,
  products: [
    {
      _id: {
        $oid: "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b2",
      },
      product: 1,
      vendor: 1,
      quantity: 2,
    },
    {
      _id: {
        $oid: "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b3",
      },
      product: 2,
      vendor: 1,
      quantity: 1,
    },
    {
      _id: {
        $oid: "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b4",
      },
      product: 4,
      vendor: 2,
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  createdAt: {
    $date: "2020-06-21T06:46:40.111Z",
  },
  updatedAt: {
    $date: "2020-07-09T11:04:04.459Z",
  },
  __v: 0,
  totalPrice: 265,
};

// const result = words.filter((word) => word.length > 6); // useless line, you do not have variable 'words'
const f = cart.products.filter((p) => p.vendor == 1);
const products = cart.products; //better variable naming
var grouped = products.reduce((dictionary, p) => {
  dictionary[p.vendor] = dictionary[p.vendor] || [];
  dictionary[p.vendor].push(p);
  return dictionary;
}, {});
for (const p in grouped) {
  console.log(grouped[p]); //is array
}
```

**To fix this code** just delete the line where you use variable `words` coz you didn't declare such.

**To get vendor value:**
`grouped[p]` is an array. It doesn't have a property `vendor`. But you can get it with:

```
for (const p in grouped) {
  console.log(grouped[p][0].vendor);
}
```

or get an array of them:

```
let vendors = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(grouped);
```

Comment: Yes that is the correct answer for my error. and I fixed the error. thanks.
but I found a new error in my code. 
it is about reduce function that don't accept the ```Interface```
the link is below
Thanks for your kindness
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754028/reduce-function-dont-accept-the-interface-as-index-type

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you the result you are looking for:

```
let f = cart.products.map( p => p.vendor);
let newArray = f.filter((vendor,index,arr)=>vendor!==arr[index+1]);
newArray.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: it got it. it is good. but if there vendor of product is an interface ( Object ex: IUser), Does the reduce function support The Vendor object?
I actually ask a new question in link below.

Answer (score 0):

You have some extraneous code in your script.

```
const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
```

Comment: I missed to clean the code. sorry for that. Next time I will be careful about my code

Answer (score 0):

On line 36 you write `const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);` but `words` is not defined anywhere in your code and that is what generates the error.

For what concerns what you want to achieve, I am not entirely sure I understood it but, if I did, you can solve your issue like this:

```js
const cart = {
  "_id": 2,
  "owner": 7,
  "products": [{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b2"
    },
    "product": 1,
    "vendor": 1,
    "quantity": 2
  }, {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b3"
    },
    "product": 2,
    "vendor": 1,
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f06f9a4b8b878050fbc54b4"
    },
    "product": 4,
    "vendor": 2,
    "quantity": 1
  }],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-06-21T06:46:40.111Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2020-07-09T11:04:04.459Z"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "totalPrice": 265
}

const products = cart.products;

const vendors = products
  .map(product => product.vendor)
  .reduce((vendors, vendor) => {
    if (vendors.indexOf(vendor) < 0) {
      vendors.push(vendor);
    }
    return vendors;
  }, []);

const productsByVendor = products.reduce((dictionary, p) => {
  dictionary[p.vendor] = dictionary[p.vendor] || [];
  dictionary[p.vendor].push(p);
  return dictionary;
}, {});
console.log('Products grouped by vendor:\n', productsByVendor);

// in 'productsByVendor' the vendors are the keys of your object
console.log('Vendors:', Object.keys(productsByVendor));

/* if you want to retrieve the vendor of a specific product from 'productsByVendor'
 * Assumptions:
 * 1. cart.products[n].product is assumed to be a unique id (if that is not the case, you can use cart.products[n]._id instead)
 * 2. I am assuming that each product can be sold by only one vendor; if a product can be sold by more than one vendor you'll have to adjust a bit the function 
 */
getVendorIdFromGroupedProducts = (productId) => {
  for (let key of Object.keys(productsByVendor)) {
    for (let prod of productsByVendor[key]) {
      if (prod.product === productId) {
        return prod.vendor
      }
    }
  }
  return 'The product does not exist'
};
console.log('Vendor of product 1 is:', getVendorIdFromGroupedProducts(1));
console.log('Vendor of product 2 is:', getVendorIdFromGroupedProducts(2));
console.log('Vendor of product 3 is:', getVendorIdFromGroupedProducts(3));
console.log('Vendor of product 4 is:', getVendorIdFromGroupedProducts(4));
```